# Toggle class in sapui5

Tags: jquery, html, css, sapui5

I am learning sapui5 and I will design a page. This page must include a listview. I will define a line or image. This image must move to down on list. This motion will start a specific day and time.

This is my class and I want toggle `first` to `motion.`

```
.first{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
/*Kayan buton */
.motion {

    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 10s ;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%{left :0px;top: 0em; opacity:0%;}
    100% {left:0px;top: 35em; opacity:0.7%;}
}
```

I define the image in `ajanda.view.xml` file.

```
<Image src="img/red-line.png" class="first" id="imgRed"></Image>
```

Finally, `ajanda.controller.js` file:

I have tried so many combinations, but they didn't work:

This:

```
   var container = this.$();
   container.find(".first").parent().addClass("motion");
```

This:

```
   $( ".first" ).toggleClass("motion");
```

And:

```
   var oImage = new sap.ui.commons.Image(sap.ui.getCore().byId("imgRed"));
   oImage.addStyleClass("motion");
   oImage.setDecorative(false);
   oImage.placeAt("content");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be totally fine:

```
var oImage = sap.ui.getCore().byId("imgRed");
oImage.toggleStyleClass("motion");
```

You might need to use `this.byId("imgRed");` instead of `sap.ui.getCore().byId("imgRed");` if you are in a component-based environment.

If you are only using UI5 to enrich your site code should look more like this:

```
// where "content" is the ID of the HTML-Element the UI5 control should be rendered in
var oImage = new sap.ui.commons.Image("imgRed", {
  src: "img/red-line.png"
}).addStyleClass("first").placeAt("content");
oImage.toggleStyleClass("motion");
```

Comment: first opinion solve my problem. But ı tried implement second opinion , I define a div tag my page `<core:HTML content"&lt;div id=&quot;badge7&quot; &gt; &lt;/div&gt;"></core:HTML>` , and I say `placeAt("`badge7");`. but it didnt work. Bagde7 my content.

Comment: then stick to the first one... btw upvotes are appreciated for helpful answers ;)